# Eslint hangs on parsing for mac and runs out of memory

Tags: visual-studio-code, out-of-memory, eslint

Running eslint on macOs 13.2.1 , with 16gb of memory seems to hang on the first parsing and crashes on Vs Code.

the command

```bash
DEBUG=eslint:*,eslintrc:*  npx eslint --fix apps/**/*.ts
```

Hangs with an output such as

```
  eslint:linter Verify +1ms
  eslint:linter With ConfigArray: someFile.app.ts +0ms
  eslint:linter Parsing: someFile.app.ts +1ms
```

The file is ridiculously simple having 9 loc

Vs code output for eslint shows the out of memory error

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[14915:0x130008000]   253332 ms: Scavenge 16144.8 (16413.5) -> 16141.4 (16430.8) MB, 22.5 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.603, current mu = 0.886) allocation failure 
[14915:0x130008000]   268734 ms: Mark-sweep 16154.7 (16430.8) -> 16145.6 (16437.8) MB, 15312.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.477, current mu = 0.025) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

It does not seem to happen on the pipeline but it is unusable on the terminal or on VS Code locally.

### Info

eslint: ^8.40.0
node v16.20.0 through nvm 0.39.3

Comment: Same issue :)

Using sveltekit

Comment: I am facing the same issue in Mac os. Tried quite a few things but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Are you still getting this problem? What if you put `"eslint.runtime.execArgv": ["--max_old_space_size=4096"]` or larger value of space? see also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1545

Comment: also possibly related: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/1192

Comment: max_old_space_size did not solved it .

Comment: I am using CDK that makes a fair amount of files. Even though cdk.out is on eslitnignore, vscode ignore and so on it still crashes. Deleting cdk.out solves it

Comment: The same thing, I had some files (which were in ignore section in my eslint config) which hanged the task. Even if I run it for the single file...

Comment: Just suddenly run into this after upgrading a dependency package's version. None of our own eslint config nor source files were changed